# Authorization in Google Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, angular2-services

I was trying to build a website in `Angular2`. The website fetches part of data from `Google firebase`. This website does not take any user login information.

Now, I am facing the following problem:

I want to ensure that only the requests originated from my hosted website, say `abc.com`, are served. No one else should be able to call the API end points using postman etc.

Currently, if I query the Firebase URL "https://mywesbite-xxxxx.firebaseio.com/data.json", the entire data is visible as a `.json` from any web-browser. I want this link to show access denied.

Comment: You should definately go with Private account where they will give you access to only authorized person with specific credentials.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to look over the [Firebase Security & Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) that you can assign your database.

Right now I assume your rules are empty or set as

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": false
  }
}
```

I don't believe you can setup anything which checks if your request comes from `abc.com` but you can check against Authenticated Users on your site to ensure that they are signed in before they can access any of your information.

There is also a good plugin which helps create Firebase Database Rules which was created by the Firebase Team. It's called [Bolt](https://github.com/firebase/bolt).

Comment: I have already read this. If I put `read` equal to `true`, anyone can see the data.

Comment: Correct, you need to define your rules around the reading of your data. I don't think you can check what domain the request comes from, but you can structure your data better to ensure only public data is readable and lock everything else behind a authorised user request.